# Bash alias to backup folder to tar.gz

Tags: bash, zsh, tar

```
alias backupfolder='tar -zcvf $1_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').tar.gz $1'
```

This alias creates the tar archive, but the naming is just `__YYYY-MM-DD.tar.gz`.
I'm trying to get `folder__YYYY-MM-DD.tar.gz`.

Do i need some special symbols in the `$1` before `_`?

Comment: You should probably use a function instead of an alias

Comment: The immediate problem is that `1_` is a valid parameter name; use `${1}_$(...)` to prevent `_` from being treated as part of the parameter expansion.

Comment: You *could* use `$1\_`, but `${1}_` is clearer and less susceptible to poor quoting.

Comment: Actually both $1\\_ and ${1} didnt take the parameter. so filename was _YYYY-MM-DD.tar.gz

Answer (score 3):

Use a function.

```
backupfolder() { tar -zcvf "${1}_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').tar.gz" "$1"; }
```

or a script in your path.

Comment: Went back to edit and had connection issues. Thanks to chepner for adding my curlies and quotes. :)